# Where can I find detailed info about creating Text user interface (TUI) [Character User Interface (CUI)]?

Tags: c++, tui

I would be very gratefull for the links for material with detailed info about creating the API for Text user interface (TUI) [Character User Interface (CUI)] which can be used in console mode even. It is interesting for me how to create such API, it is more interesting then using existing "black box" by other programmers. I didn't find nothing still.

Comment: Well look no further: The default mode of console applications *is* text and characters, so you have your UI interface functions alread built into the language with `std::cout` and `std::cin`. I'm sorry for being a little sarcastic, but the standard output and input functionality in C++ is all you need for a text-based user interface.

Comment: You may want to research text positioning API, such as `ncurses`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, I know it. I don't understand how to do updating the screen, for visual effects emulation (window moving or resizing, for example).

Comment: If you want a more window-like functionality, it depends on platform. On POSIX-type systems (e.g. Linux or OSX) use e.g. [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), I think there are similar libraries for Windows and the Windows console too.

Comment: Thank you. But it is already existing API. Is exist an detailed info (maybe a book) how *to create* such API (its *principles* and *ideas*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years ago I found a book ( yes a paper book:) ),  called Advanced C Programming for Displays.  This explained the basics of creating a text editor with windows and pulldown menus.  you can get this book on amazon.   I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Most the books you want are old, try restricting your search to before 1995.  "Designing Screen Interfaces in C" is good and last time I checked the source code is available at the author's website.

I second the "Advanced C Programming for Displays" suggestion.

"The Craft of Text Editing: Emacs for the Modern World" has gotten incredible reviews, but is about a very specific kind of TUI.

Answer (score 0):

There's unlikely to be detailed information on "how to create a UI" - that's far too large a thing.

What you might be interested in are some of the lower-level building blocks; things like the DEC VTxxx terminal control sequences, ECMA 35/48, xterm and so on. All of these have extensive documentation on how the control systems work.